# SQL, Firebird, Dynamic Union based on other Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, firebird, unpivot

I need your help. I need to build a dynamic union SQL Statement.
(Or Stored Procedure)

In **TableA1** there are the values stored for my SQL Parameters.
For Example:

```
ID | Name
1 | 16
2 | 23
3 | 30
```

In **TableB1** there are all other values stored. But I need for every row in TableA1 a union

For example:

```
Select b.* from TableB1 b
join TableA1 a on a.ID = b.ID
where b.ID = 1
union
Select b.* from TableB1
join TableA1 a on a.ID = b.ID
where b.ID = 2
```

Because TableA1 is dynamic, it is not possible to make a static union-sql. Please help me. Could I do this maybe with: cte WITH ?

Best regards
rf

Second Explanation:
I will try to make my explanation more understandable. Sorry for my first question. I see it was not correct.

I need a dynamic union (or something else) because of the table design of TableB1. The values stored each month/years in horizontal way.

Example **TableB1**:

```
date    | xxxx | ID1 |  ID2 | ID3 | ID4 ...
2014-07 | n    |  20 |   30 |  40 |
2014-08 | n    |  40 |   50 |  70 |
```

The output should look like this:

```
TableB1.date | TableA1.ID | TableA1.Name | TableB1.ID x |
2014-07      |          1 |         16   |    20    
2014-08      |          1 |         16   |    40
2014-07      |          2 |         23   |    30      
2014-08      |          2 |         23   |    50
2014-07      |          3 |         30   |    40      
2014-08      |          3 |         30   |    70
```

I thought I will put the sql into a stored procedure, because for each union I have to change the SQL Syntax to get the right column.

Maybe I have to make a unpivot Stored Procedure first. Do you have any idea how I could make this in Firebird?

Comment: Can you provide some sample expected output? Why can't you just do: `Select b.* from TableB1 b join TableA1 a on a.ID = b.ID`?

Comment: Reading your query, and your issue, what I'm seeing is you're selecting TableB1's contents for the union, and not doing anything with TableA1. Also of note: why not avoid the union and use the [IN predicate](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-predicates.html#nullguide-pred-in)?

Comment: Is this Firebird or SQL-Server? Why both tags?

Comment: @Frazz: Because the Software could use by installation Firebird or MSSQL Database. Both databases are supported-

Comment: TableB1's structure is obviously the problem. You want to use TableA1's ID to select a column from TableB1. Can't you restructure TableB1 to have one row per date and ID, plus one column of values? That would be the best solution to query and maintain. Otherwise you will need complex CASE statements or a STORED PROCEDURE. But neither will be flexible enough to adapt itself when you will add new IDs in TableA1 (and new columns in TableB1).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the field xxxx in TableB1 represents but i am assuming that you do not have an ID field in TableB1, and for each ID in TableA1 you want the corresponding IDx field from TableB1. I am also assuming that your ID fields are numeric and the Name is Numeric.
Here is an example code inside EXECUTE BLOCK, but can easily be put into a STORED PROCEDURE. The reason for the execute block is that is makes it flexible if being executed via ADO for example.

I expanded on the idea that Frazz said to restructure the TableB1.

You will need the following Temp Table

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GTT_TEMP (
    DT   VARCHAR(10),
    ID   INTEGER,
    VAL  INTEGER
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

and here is the SQL

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
returns (TableB1_DATE VARCHAR(10),
         TableA1_ID INTEGER,
         tableA1_Name INTEGER,
         tableB1_ID INTEGER )
as
declare variable sql varchar(1000);
declare variable id integer;
begin

    for
    Select TABLEA1.ID FROM TABLEA1
    INTO :id
    do
    begin
       sql = 'INSERT INTO GTT_TEMP ( DT, ID, VAL ) SELECT tableb1."DATE", '||:id||', ID'||:id||' from tableb1 WHERE tableb1.ID'||:id||' > 0' ;
       EXECUTE Statement :sql;
    end

    FOR 
    Select GTT_TEMP.DT, GTT_TEMP.ID, tablea1.NAME, GTT_TEMP.VAL from GTT_TEMP, TABLEA1 WHERE tablea1.ID = gtt_temp.ID
    INTO :TableB1_DATE,
         :TableA1_ID,
         :TableA1_NAME,
         :TableB1_ID
     DO
     BEGIN
        suspend;
     END

END
```